# Identifying iPad WiFi from iPad 3G Programmatically

Tags: iphone

i know that [UIDevice currentDevice].model will give me the name of the device currently running my application. What i want to know is whether there is a way to differentiate an iPad with Wifi only from an iPad with 3G connectivity or not. I do not have the hardware and the emulator gives only iPad Simulator.  Any one knows?

cheers
AF

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: there are many reasons Dov, the iPad 3G + Wifi has a real GPS unit and cellular data. My app needs to know this information to advise accordingly (e.g. there is no point giving the user the config option for "big uploads on cellular data" if no cellular data connection is possible!)